# How to interact id of each other of two select box on submit

Tags: php, mysql

I have minimum of two select box in HTML form to insert through POST but user can add more select boxes. Now I have to show relations between each n every inserted id.

[image]

like we have inserted 1,4,9,6 id. So I want it inserted in a table in two column as:

```
(1-4) (1-9) (1-6) (4-9) (4-6) (9-6)
```

Comment: i want to insert those two values in two columns of database i.e Col 1 Col 2

Comment: please check out my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = $_POST['text'];

$textname = explode(",", $text);

if ($textname > 0) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($textname); $i++) {
        "Piece $i = $textname[$i] <br />";
        ..... insert query....
```

I'm getting POST values in Piece $i...how to insert this in that array in your code

Comment: Danila, you have edited my answer until it is unrecognisable - why not just post your own alternative? It isn't really clear what the poster wants and between us we might be able to clarify that. I have assumed s/he can process the $_POST array to create the list s/he wants.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my original answer, to what I think is the crux of the question - how to generate e.g. the pairs (1-2) (1-3) (1-4) (1-5) (2-3) (2-4) (2-5) (3-4) (3-5) (4-5) from 1,2,3,4,5. I think we need more info from the poster if s/he needs help processing the $_POST array

```
$arrIDs = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
$intUpperLimit = max($arrIDs);
foreach($arrIDs as $ID) {
  for($i = $ID + 1; $i <= $intUpperLimit; $i++) {
    echo("INSERT INTO tblPairs VALUES($ID, $i)");
  }
}
```

If the values are not consecutive as your original example suggested, then use

```
$arrIDs = array(1,5,9,17); 
foreach($arrIDs as $ID1) { 
    $arrUsedIDs[] = $ID1;
    foreach(array_diff($arrIDs, $arrUsedIDs) as $ID2) {
      echo("INSERT INTO similar_ailment (ailment,ailment1) VALUES($ID1, $ID2)"); 
    } 
}
```

To insert two values in a DB, you should create a stored procedure e.g.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `usp_insert_pair`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `usp_insert_pair`( 
  IN  p_intID1 INT, 
  IN  p_intID2 INT,
  OUT  p_row_count INT
  )
BEGIN  
  INSERT INTO tblPairs (intID1, intID1) 
  VALUES (p_intID1, p_intID1); 
  SELECT ROW_COUNT() INTO p_row_count;
  END; $$
DELIMITER ;
```

The procedure takes the pair as inputs, and provide an output (which you may or may not find helpful). You can the incorporate a call of the stored procedure into the loop

```
$arrIDs = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
$intUpperLimit = max($arrIDs);
foreach($arrIDs as $ID) {
  for($i = $ID + 1; $i <= $intUpperLimit; $i++) {
    mysqli_query($conn, "usp_insert_pair($ID, $i, @p_row_count, @p_insert_id)");
  }
}
```

You need to set up your connection to the DB first of course - that is the $conn parameter. When calling mysqli_query, you should check the operation was successful. There are a number of options here. mysqli_query returns false on failure, so you could inspect the value returned

```
    $bOutcome = mysqli_query($conn, "usp_insert_pair($ID, $i, @p_row_count, @p_insert_id)");
    if (!$bOutcome) echo "row insert error for pair $ID, $i";
```

You might want to bail out if an insert doesn't work

```
    $rs = mysqli_query($conn, $strSQL) or Die("Error in usp_insert_pair: ". mysqli_error($conn));
```

and you might want to inspect the @intRowCount parameter that is returned to ensure that 1 row (and only one row) was added.

```
    $rs = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT @intRowCount')
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($rs);
    if ($row[0] != 1) echo "row insert error for pair $ID, $i";
```

There is a lot more checking you could do but I'm trying to keep it (relatively) brief.

Comment: $text=$_POST['text'];                

 $textname=explode(",", $text);      
   
foreach ($textname as $value)
{
  
  $sql1=mysql_query("select * from abc where xyz='$value'");
                       while( $sha1=mysql_fetch_array($sql1))  
        $idd=$sha1['id'];
    $tex=explode(",", $idd); 
 for($i = 0; $i < count($tex); $i++){
 echo $tex[$i] ;
 
 $arrIDs = array(" ??? ");
$intUpperLimit = max($arrIDs);
foreach($arrIDs as $ID) {
  for($i = $ID + 1; $i <= $intUpperLimit; $i++) {
    echo("INSERT INTO similar_ailment (ailment,ailment1) VALUES($ID, $i)");
  }
}
}
 
}

Comment: how to pass $tex[ $i ] value to array

Comment: Please take the time to say clearly what you want. I think your question is now how to create the array on this line, $arrIDs = array(" ??? "), based on the $_POST array? If that is the case, you need to say more to explain the lines preceding it.

Comment: sir i think your loop is for (1 to 4) if 1 & 4 are inputs...i want only (1 , 4) to be stored in two columns. if 1,5,9 are inputs..i want (1,5)(1,9)(5,9) to be stored in three rows in database

Comment: updated answer, see "If the values are not consecutive .."

Comment: $shailu3=$_POST['bacteria'];
                                                                                                                                
  $singh3=implode($shailu3,",");                                         how to insert $singh3 value to that array

Comment: I'm not a mind reader. I do not know the context of your code. Can you give an example value for $singh3.